# Custom lint rule for the `when condition` check

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, jetbrains-ide, lint

I am using Gson's serialization adapter `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` for serializing data based on **disciminator**. However when there is an unknwon discriminator (coming from the API) and not defined on Client, the `TypeAdapter` will be null.

In this case if I have a kotlin when condition check as:

```
when(fooType){
 is fooA -> //blaba
 is fooB -> //blaba
 //else or null is not handled
}
```

and `fooType` is `null`, it will crash as `null` condition is not handled.
Is there any way to to create a **custom lint rule (Detector)** to check for for **when conditions** (instanceof in java) if they implement an `else` or `null` check and inject that on Android Studio inspection?

Answer (score 5):

I don't really have experience with writing custom lint checks, but I think something like this (although it's not optimal and you **shouldn't** use it as it is since it only shows the idea) might work.

```
class WhenNullElseMissingDetector : Detector(), Detector.UastScanner {

    override fun getApplicableUastTypes(): MutableList<Class<out UElement>> =
        mutableListOf(USwitchExpression::class.java)

    override fun createUastHandler(context: JavaContext): UElementHandler = WhenNullElseMissingHandler(context)
}

class WhenNullElseMissingHandler(private val context: JavaContext) : UElementHandler() {

    override fun visitSwitchExpression(node: USwitchExpression) {
        if (node.psi?.javaClass != KtWhenExpression::class.java) {
            // returning early here, so it doesn't go false positive on java switches
            return
        }

        var hasNullClause = false
        var hasElseClause = false

        node.body.expressions.forEach { clause ->
             // checking the child's text here just for a example, you should
             // probably check if child's class is KtWhenConditionIsPattern,
             // KtWhenConditionWithExpression or LeafPsiElement
            val clauseText = clause.psi?.firstChild?.text

            if ("null" == clauseText) {
                hasNullClause = true
            } else if ("else" == clauseText) {
                hasElseClause = true
            }
        }

        if (!hasElseClause) {
            context.report(
                WHEN_NULL_OR_ELSE_MISSING, node, context.getLocation(node),
                "When expression must include an else case"
            )
        }

        if (!hasNullClause) {
            context.report(
                WHEN_NULL_OR_ELSE_MISSING, node, context.getLocation(node),
                "When expression must include a null case"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you'll have to add your new detector to the IssueRegistry.
Assuming that you have your lint checks in a separate java/kotlin module, it might look like this

```
package com.example.lintchecks

// omit imports

val WHEN_NULL_OR_ELSE_MISSING = Issue.create(
    "MY_ISSUE_ID",
    "A brief to show in a one line popup",
    "More detailed explanation",
    Category.CORRECTNESS,
    5,
    Severity.WARNING,
    Implementation(
        WhenNullElseMissingDetector::class.java,
        Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE
    )
)

class MyIssueRegistry : IssueRegistry() {
    override val issues: List<Issue>
        get() = listOf(WHEN_NULL_OR_ELSE_MISSING)

}
```

Library module's build.gradle file should have `com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.4.0` (or whichever version is relevant) `compileOnly` dependency and a block like this

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Lint-Registry-v2": "com.example.lintchecks.MyIssueRegistry")
    }
}
```